# what is the best way to handle access control in laravel and vuejs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, access-control

I'm new to Vue and I trying to change my old laravel application to SPA, I watch this tutorial and on it, the instructor stores the user data in `window.user` to make it available on all components. but it can easily be changed and honestly, I think it is the worst idea ever.

is there any better solution for ACL in the front end?
please help me out.

by the way, I'm using laravel 5.7 and previously I've used Laratrust for ACL purpose.

this is tutorial's link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sW6MStdkFJE&list=PLB4AdipoHpxaHDLIaMdtro1eXnQtl_UvE&index=45

Comment: You can encode user's role in Cookie, make Cookie http-only and check role in the middleware for each request

Comment: How to do this? can you show example. thank you

Comment: you mean state management in front-end? when Api returned a success data, use js-cookie library for creating and accessing cookies in your ACTION and commit a MUTATION to update the state. You need Vuex